# Can a MFC dialog resource be attached to a CChildView?

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2017

I have a single document MFC app, which consists of the `MainFrame` (derived from CFrameWnd) and within contained `CChildView` (derived form `CWnd`). These are generated by the VS MFC Wizard.

In resource editor I have designed a simple UI and tagged it as `IDD_CUSTOMCONTROL`  with few buttons and text fields. I would like to connect it to the `CChildView` without generating it as a new dialog.

What is the right way to do it? Is it possible to do it? Or should I connect the ID directly to `MainFrame`?

EDIT: I have just found the right [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ayf8605.aspx) which states which classes can have dialog id's assigned.

The scope of the question is depleted. Can/should it be closed? Or can I ask how to achieve my goal and apply the designed resource to MainFrame? (The title is now misleading).

Comment: You can answer your own question.

Comment: Umm, maybe confused a little? A "view" is window (a `CWnd`-derived class) displaying and modifying the "document" (call `GetDocument()`). `CView` is the base-class, while `CFormView` is the derivative that can display a dialog resource. So your view class must be derived from `CFormView` - and  no, the frame window has nothing to do with resources or the document. As an advice, try to NOT `#include` the view's header file (childview.h ?) in the document's source (the opposite is necessary, of course, ie the view must "know" the document).

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou: Yes I am actually on this: Connecting the resource to `CFormView`, which in my case is the MainFrame (Parent Window). As soon as I get this I will provide the answer to question together with the solution to the problem.

Comment: "Connecting the resource to CFormView, which in my case is the MainFrame (Parent Window)" - this is wrong! The view and the frame are separate classes. Your view must be derived from `CFormView` (the MainFrame could be left as is). Better create a new test project with the wizard, initially deriving the view from `CFormView`, to see how it is done.

Comment: Ok, thank you for pointing that out. If I understand correct, I will have the CFormView as MainFrame which will encapsulate also a CFormView that will be connected to the resource dialog.

Comment: Sorry, still wrong. Your view must be derived from CFormView, and your CMainFrame from CFrameWnd (which is the default, and most likely still is). A frame window is NOT a view.

Comment: Yes, you are correct thank you. I checked that wrong. MainFrame is CFrameWnd and I have just created new class derived from CFormView. I will attempt to display it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: No.

I have just found the right [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ayf8605.aspx) which states which classes can have dialog id's assigned.

> Classes such as `CButton`, `CWnd`, or `CDocument`, which do not require a
> dialog ID or resource ID. These classes do not use a dialog or
> resource ID. If you select one of these classes for your base class,
> the Dialog ID box and the DHTML resource ID box are dimmed.
>
> Classes such as `CDialog`, `CFormView`, or `CPropertyPage`, which *require* a
> dialog ID.
>
> The class `CDHtmlDialog`, which requires a dialog ID, a DHTML resource
> ID, and an HTML file name.

I should go with `CFormView` instead as @ConstantineGeorgiou proposed in comments.