# How to show CFormView in CWnd in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a SDI MFC App without Document/View support. I want to embed the CFormView with controls designed in resource editor in ChildView. How do I do that?

The MFC Wizard generated 3 files:

- App.cpp (derived from `CWinApp`)
- MainFrame.cpp (derived from `CFrameWnd`)
- ChildView.cpp (derived from `CWnd`)

Now, I have generated custom class that derives from `CFormView`, where `IDD_MYVIEW` is the generated ID to resource GUI.

```
class MyFormView: public CFormView
{
public:
    enum { IDD = IDD_MYVIEW  };

    MyFormView(): CFormView(IDD) {};
    virtual ~MyFormView() {};
}
```

How do I display this MyFormView in ChildView?

As I tried generating the project again and checked in the MFC wizard the Document/View architecture checkbox and changed the base class of View to CFormView. I realized that the App initialization is different than the initially generated one.

Currently the first app is initialized as follows:

```
BOOL MfcApp::InitInstance() 
{
    // (...)

    CMainFrame* pFrame = new CMainFrame;
    if (!pFrame)
        return FALSE;
    m_pMainWnd = pFrame;
    // create and load the frame with its resources
    pFrame->LoadFrame(IDR_MAINFRAME,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | FWS_ADDTOTITLE, NULL,
        NULL);

    // The one and only window has been initialized, so show and update it
    pFrame->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
    pFrame->UpdateWindow();
    return TRUE;
}
```

furthermore the MainFrame initializes the ChildView in the OnCreate method.

```
int CMainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CFrameWnd::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

    // create a view to occupy the client area of the frame
    if (!m_wndView.Create(NULL, NULL, AFX_WS_DEFAULT_VIEW, CRect(0, 0, 0, 0), this, AFX_IDW_PANE_FIRST, NULL))
    {
        TRACE0("Failed to create view window\n");
        return -1;
    }
}
```

where `m_wndView` is the `ChildView`. I think that I should initialize the `CFormView` in `OnCreate` method of the `ChildView`, but I don't know how to do that nor how to "show" it. Because the `CFormView` does not have these methods.

On the other hand the initialization with the Doc/View architecture looks like this. And seems to automatically cover what I want to achieve.

```
BOOL MfcApp::InitInstance() 
{
    // (...)
    CSingleDocTemplate* pDocTemplate;
    pDocTemplate = new CSingleDocTemplate(
        IDR_MAINFRAME,
        RUNTIME_CLASS(CMFCPlaygroundDoc),
        RUNTIME_CLASS(CMainFrame),       
        RUNTIME_CLASS(CMFCPlaygroundView)); // <-- derived from CFormView
    if (!pDocTemplate)
        return FALSE;
    AddDocTemplate(pDocTemplate);
    // (...)
}
```

The thing is, I see that in the second generated Project the CFormView is provided to the SingleDocTemplate constructor and I could place my controls there. But in the first generated project I don't know where I could connect the CFormView to displayed ChildView. I don't know how and where can I connect my new CFormView.

I find the Doc/View architecture overwhelming and unnecessary for the app I need and would like to proceed with it just for the sake of understanding it.

Comment: When you design your project you choose a SDI or a MDI project. A single or multi document interface. Your document is associated with a view. At project design time you decide what type of view you are going to use. So the project will provide you with a skeleton form for you to add your controls to. I don't quite see what your problem is?

Comment: Why create a SDI without a doc/view? You are making it hard for yourself. If all you want is a dialog then why not make a dialog based project instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a MFC dialog resource be attached to a CChildView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48524464/can-a-mfc-dialog-resource-be-attached-to-a-cchildview)

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I created the project first without Doc/View, because I wasn't familiar with that architecture and found it overwhelming at first. Currently in order to continue my project I have checked the Doc/View architecture in MFC Wizard. 

This question is a succession of the proposed duplicate (I am the author of the latter as well).

Comment: try here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5445/Using-views-effectively-without-the-doc-view-overh

Comment: good resource. If you plan to maintain a resizable window layout despite the fixed dialog form, I recommend ResizableLib ( https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1175/ResizableLib -- there is a SDI demo as well ). Making the form resizable seems to me the only challengs here.

Comment: Multiple views for SDI: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s199bks0.aspx)

Comment: @RonTLV: Could you post the link as an answer? The content from the link is a spot on and helped me understand my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since @RonTLV didn't post his Link as an answer, I will interpret how I could fix my problem with the [Link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5445/Using-views-effectively-without-the-doc-view-overh) @RonTLV provided.

In short: I was missing the DYNCREATE macros for my CFormView class and in the MainFrame (`CFrameWnd`) there needs to be a pointer instead of instance to the CFormView, which in the OnCreate method of MainFrame must be downcasted (via macro).

Below you can find the `CFormView` class header with necessary macros:

```
class MyFormView : public CFormView
{
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(MyFormView)

public:
    enum { IDD = IDD_RANGERCONTROLS  };

    MyFormView();// : CFormView(IDD) {};
    virtual ~MyFormView();

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

public:
};
```

In the cpp file I have added the `IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE` macro as shown below:

```
IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(MyFormView, CFormView)

MyFormView::MyFormView()
    : CFormView(MyFormView::IDD)
{
};

MyFormView::~MyFormView()
{
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(MyFormView, CFormView)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

And finally in the `MainFrame::OnCreate` method

```
CCreateContext ccx;
ccx.m_pNewViewClass = RUNTIME_CLASS(MyFormView);
m_pMainView = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(MyFormView, this->CreateView(&ccx));

if (NULL == m_pMainView)
{
    TRACE0("Creation of View failed.\n");
}

RecalcLayout();
m_pMainView->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
m_pMainView->OnInitialUpdate();
SetActiveView(m_pMainView);
```

where, `m_pMainView` is declared as the private member of CMainFrame:

```
MyFormView* m_pMainView;
```