# How to refresh a Groupbox control in MFC (C++)

Tags: c++, mfc, controls, groupbox

I created a Groupbox in my MFC view class. But failed in refresh it while Restore Down from Maxmize as well as Maxmize from Restore Down.

[image: The failed refresh Groupbox control as below pic:]

I create the Groupbox in `View::OnCreate`:

```
int Cmfc_gui_test3View::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
...
CRect mybox( 0, 0,350, 1000);

pmyGroupBox->Create(_T("Test GroupBox"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_CENTER | BS_GROUPBOX|WS_BORDER, mybox, this, IDG_GROUPBOX1);
...
}
```

And I am using `pmyGroupbox->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE)` and `pmyGroupbox->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW)` in `OnPaint` method. I also tested `pmyGroupbox->ShowWindow(SW_RESTORE)` but no lucky. The control always failed in refreshing itself.
Hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn’t call ShowWindow in your OnPaint handler. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: What I am doing is to develop a GUI: in the client window, there is a Groupbox on the left side,  which will contain all the controls(button, Combobox, Listbox, etc.); On the right side, a living video will be displayed.

Comment: Moreover, actually I would like to put the Groupbox on the right side. But when I use GetClientRect(&rect) in OnCreate, both rect.right and rect.bottom return 0. So I failed to put it on the right. But this is another a problem. Maybe I should create a different thread for this issue.

Comment: But why do you have to do all this manually? Why can't you use the Resource Editor? Do me, a view is a representation of a document. This is why it is called the document / view architecture. So teh document has the underlying data and the view renders the document visually. It is not normally used to render controls which are usually part of dialogs or docking panes.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, but how to add a Groupbox through Resource Editor? I am using VS 2015, MFC; I am not using CLR Windows or Winform programming.

Comment: I mean to add a Groupbox to the client window, not a dialog. So far I only see how to add controls to a dialog in the resource editor. OR do you mean I can embed a dialog in the client window which contains the groupbox?

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Hi IInspectable, now I am using CFormView solution as Andrew suggested. Give me time and I will prepare a new updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question ([Can a MFC dialog resource be attached to a CChildView?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48524464/2287576)) should provide useful information.

You need to use the [`CFormView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cformview-class?view=msvc-170) class if you want to create a form that has controls on it, like combo boxes.

There are some other useful articles on this subject:

[Q98598: HOWTO: Use `CFormView` in SDI and MDI Applications](https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/098/Q98598/)

The linked article provides sample code and instructions. The summary reads:

> ## SUMMARY
>
> The `CFormView` class provides a convenient method to place controls
> into a view that is based on a dialog box template. The general
> procedure to use a `CFormView` is described in the documentation for the
> class and is illustrated in the VIEWEX and CHKBOOK sample applications
> provided with Microsoft Foundation Classes (MFC) versions 2.x and
> above. However, these applications do not demonstrate making the
> initial size of the frame window to be the same as the initial size of
> the form.
>
> The following section lists the steps required to support creating a
> single document interface (SDI) or multiple document interface (MDI)
> application based on a `CFormView`, sizing the initial frame window
> around the form, changing the style of the frame, and closing an MDI
> document using a button in the form.

The instructions are for older versions of Visual Studio so you might have to tweak a little.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your help and I appreciate it very much. Now I built a CFormView based MFC application and I added Groupbox via Resouce Editor. I have a perfect Groupbox without any garbage showing while moving and sizing. The only issue I found is that the Groupbox is not zooming properly with the client window. Anyway, I will further debug this.